# Qt applications settings

Tags: qt, application, settings

where's the path in which Qt application will save default settings for all users? Wanted to set out some default settings for an old clumsy person...
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

There's no such thing for Qt applications as "default settings for all users".

You could e.g. use `/etc/skel` to prepopulate the required settings for the applications you're interested in.

At least in RedHat/Fedora based distros this directory is copied to the user's home directory recursively but I'm not sure if it applies to other distros as well.